# how to perform click on an element using selenium for which i am getting StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation, browser-automation

Problem: there are couple of radio button with same id and I need to perform click on these. The first radio button gets the click where the second one is getting `StaleElementReferenceException`.

Can Anybody Suggest me how it can be handled so that when I click the second radio button it does not throw `StaleElementReferenceException`

HTML:

```
<solvup-radio-type _ngcontent-c7="" _nghost-c10=""><div _ngcontent-c10="" class="validation-error ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid">

    <solvup-label _ngcontent-c10="" _nghost-c33=""><label _ngcontent-c33="" class="control-label">
     Have you been able to resolve the issue based on this information? <!----><span _ngcontent-c33="" class="required-mark">*</span> 
</label>
<solvup-tooltip _ngcontent-c33="" _nghost-c36=""><!---->
</solvup-tooltip>
</solvup-label>

  <!----><div _ngcontent-c10="" class="radio">
      <label _ngcontent-c10="">
          <input _ngcontent-c10="" type="radio" id="ts_note_questions" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid">
          Yes, issue is resolved - close case
      </label>

  </div><div _ngcontent-c10="" class="radio">
      <label _ngcontent-c10="">
          <input _ngcontent-c10="" type="radio" id="ts_note_questions" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid">
          No - continue to next step
      </label>

  </div>
</div>
<solvup-hint-text _ngcontent-c10="" _nghost-c34=""><!----><p _ngcontent-c34="" class="help-block"></p>
</solvup-hint-text>
<solvup-validation-messages _ngcontent-c10="" _nghost-c35=""><!---->



<!----><div _ngcontent-c35="" class="form-group">
     <small _ngcontent-c35="" class="err"><i _ngcontent-c35="" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>  Please select an option</small>
</div>

</solvup-validation-messages>


</solvup-radio-type>
```

Selenium Code:

```
 @Given("^User fills details in First of Five Troubleshooting  page$")
public void user_fills_details_in_First_of_Five_Troubleshooting_page() throws Throwable {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    List<WebElement> li = driver.findElements(By.className("radio"));
    Actions ob = new Actions(driver);
    ob.moveToElement(li.get(1));
    ob.click(li.get(1));
    Action action = ob.build();
    action.perform();   
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: StaleElement generally comes when the dom of the page is reloaded when action is performed.. to solve this you can wait for few seconds to reload the page & then re-locate web elements and perform action

Comment: @ShekharSwami I applied implicit wait. but its not working

Comment: implicit won't work.. Thread.sleep

Comment: @ShekharSwami As you can see in the code i am already using thread.sleep but it is not working either

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the dom-structure, you might be trying to click an element that might not be the right one. I would think

```
List<WebElement> li = driver.findElements(By.Id("ts_note_questions"));
Actions ob = new Actions(driver);
ob.moveToElement(li.get(1));
action.perform();  
li.get(1).click();
```

would work, as you are trying to click on the input instead of the div.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you copied the first radio-button but it looks like you forgot to change the id of the second radio-button. Try to change the id of the second radio-button to a unique one.

Comment: Did you mean to change the id of the second radio button to something unique in the html? if this is what it is than i cannot do that.. Please suggest with the existing html

Comment: Then try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838302/how-do-i-distinguish-between-two-elements-having-same-ids-on-same-page-using-sel

Comment: @shreya_bhatngr - xpath indexing is not working ??

`(//input[@type='radio'])[1]` - points to 1st radio button
`(//input[@type='radio'])[2]` - points to 2nd radio button
`(//input[@type='radio'])[3]` - points to 3rd radio button